# Convolution of two functions doesn't fit my data as I thought it would

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, convolution

I have simulated a Gaussian curve in 50 bins of data. I have then repeated this many times, drawing the amplitude of the Gaussian from a log-normal distribution. Here are a 10 realizations:

(**IMAGE 1**)
[image]

I actually create 10,000 realizations, I take the sum of the 50 bins (that you see above) for each of the 10,000 realizations and then I plot a histogram of the result:

(**IMAGE 2**)
[image]

This histogram is a log-normal distribution, which I think makes sense because I am drawing the amplitudes (of my Gaussian curves) from a log-normal distribution.

So when I plot a log-normal curve over the top, it fits well:

(**IMAGE 3**)
[image]

Now to make the situation more realistic, I am adding lots of noise to my Gaussian signals, so now they look more like:

(**IMAGE 4**)
[image]

Now when I plot my histogram, the log-normal curve no longer matches the data. This is because of the noise that I have added of course:

(**IMAGE 5**)
[image]

To find the function that best describes my histogram now, I believe that I have to take the **convolution** of my log-normal curve and a Gaussian curve that describes the distribution of the noise that I added.

Here is the histogram of the noise I added along with a Gaussian curve fitting the data (mean -0.07 standard deviation 42.89):

(**IMAGE 6**)
[image]

So I believe that to describe the shape of the histogram in **IMAGE 5**, I need to convolve the dashed line in **IMAGE 5** with the dashed line in **IMAGE 6**:

(**IMAGE 7**)
[image]

So I try to do that convolution and I get the blue curve:

(**IMAGE 8**)
[image]

So then to check if this convolution does indeed describe my histogram from **IMAGE 5** I plot everything together:

(**IMAGE 9**)
[image]

As you can see the convolution still doesn't quite fit the histogram. The curve is a little too wide.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: Just to clarify what you are doing in Image 4: Are you adding gaussian noise to each of the bins of the log-normal densities? If so, i do not see why a convolution of a log-normal and a normal would give you the correct distribution. You only get a convolution of a log-normal and a normal if you add independent log-normal and normal random variables, not if you add gaussian noise to the log-normal density. But perhaps i am misunderstanding what you are doing here. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Thank you @SmallDeviation. So the curves in Image 1 are Gaussian, but their amplitudes are drawn from a log-normal distribution. And then to get to Image 4, yes I just add Gaussian noise to each bin of Image 1.